# Can't decrypt Kinesis Activity Stream: no Go SDK

Tags: go, encryption, amazon-kinesis, amazon-aurora, amazon-kms

I'm stuck trying to decrypt a Kinesis stream from an Aurora DB, and I'm following [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/DBActivityStreams.Monitoring.html).

I need to decrypt the activity event using the data key (already decrypted via the kms SDK).

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no encryption SDK for Go:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/programming-languages.html

Do you know any workaround to decrypt this in Go?
Any help is appreciated, thanks!